# Excel Formula for referencing a cell address using text contained in another cell

Tags: excel

I have a situation where am calculating the 1st 2nd and 3rd most common downtime reasons based on their numerical values.

I have formulas that sort and give me the cell address of the 1st 2nd and 3rd highest numbers (ex. $K$31) I then use replace to find address of the heading (ex. $K$20). I now want to get the text that is contained in that particular cell. These cell addresses will be variable however so I am looking for a formula that I can use to provide the text contained within that cell which could at another time be another cell. Obviously if I just type =(cell that contains $K$20) I will just be given "$K$21.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `INDIRECT()`

Comment: Wow, dead simple little function! Thanks for the help, I had never heard of that before.

Answer (score 0):

`=INDIRECT(<link to the cell with that shows $K$21 here>)`